# How can I make a test circuit and application for CA3020A power amplifier?

Tags: test-equipment

I found these components recently and am eager to work on them. I first need to check if they are working and then need to make an application with them. I referred to the data sheet but still not able to proceed.

This is the link to the [datasheet.](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1053465/Intersil/CA3020A/1)

Comment: What do you need to do?  The datasheet has examples for audio applications, and test circuits for high frequency stuff.  Are you trying to build an audio amplifier, or are you trying to amplify video signals?

Comment: Basically I should test the component if it's functioning properly and build an audio amplifier using it. So is there any way to test this component and proceed with it's application....?

Comment: Build one of the test circuits in the datasheet and see if the chip meets the specifications.

Comment: can you pls suggest the parameter that i should be checking for this amplifier in order to determine the proper functioning?

Comment: Figure 8 and measure the freqeuncy response, or just use Figure 1B and see how well it works as an amplifier.

Comment: Yes I reffered Figure 1B and having few doubts ,should I give   Vcc1=9v, vcc2=9v and ein 1 khz how should i see output and what should i observe at output  to see how well it works as an amplifier. Kindly suggest as I am beginner and have just started learning about these amplifier topics.